# Tensorflow 2.0: How is the error backpropagated to a layer when its output branches to two models learning individually?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This is more of a conceptual question, but it is related to a practical problem I am having. Suppose I define a model, as an example, something like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Dense, GlobalAveragePooling1D, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

def root(input_shape):

    input_tensor = Input(input_shape)

    cnn1 = Conv1D(100, 10, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape)(input_shape)
    mp1 = MaxPooling1D((3,))(cnn1)
    cnn3 = Conv1D(160, 10, activation='relu')(mp1)
    gap1 = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(cnn3)
    drp1 = Dropout(0.5)(gap1)

    return Model(input_tensor, drp1)
```

And then the two branches

```py
def branch_1(input_shape):

    input_tensor = Input(input_shape)
    dense1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(input_tensor)
    prediction = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense1)

    return Model(input_tensor, prediction)
```

```py
def branch_2(input_shape):

    input_tensor = Input(input_shape)
    dense1 = Dense(25, activation='relu')(input_shape)
    dropout1 = Dropout(rate=0.4)(dense1)
    prediction = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dropout1)

    return Model(input_tensor, prediction)
```

Now, I create my final model as:

```py
input_shape = (256, 1)

base_model = root(input_shape)

root_input = Input(input_shape)
root_output = base_model(root_input)

b1 = branch_1(root_output[0].shape[1:])
b1_output = b1(root_output)

b2 = branch_2(root_output[0].shape[1:])
b2_output = b2(root_output)

outputs = [b1_output, b2_output]

branched_model = Model(root_input, outputs)
```

The `root_output` is linked to both `branch_1` and `branch_2`. As such, the error propagated to the last layer of model `root` comes from the outputs of both `branch_1` and `branch_2`. My question is, how those errors are combined when propagated to the last layer of model `root`? Can I affect the way this combination is performed?

Answer (score 1):

You're not done yet, you still need to define your loss function for your model. This is where your errors are combined, for example `MSE(label1, output1) + 2* MSE(label2, output2)`.

So when you backpropagate a  batch, you calculate a vector (the gradient) that will change all the weights (in root, branch1 and branch2) so that your loss is minimized. Let's say you update your weights, and forward pass the same batch again. Now the loss will be lower (you just optimized for that batch), but loss2 (`MSE(label2, output2)`) will have dimished twice as much as loss1 (`(MSE(label1, output1)`).

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Can you give me an example of how to add this to the code above? What I did in my implementation was to simply compile the `branched_model` with a loss funtion, for instance: `branched_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])`. And I pass to `y` of `branched_model` the list `[train_y, train_y]`. Same for validation. What will happen with the loss in this case?

Comment: Compiling root, branch_1 or branch_2 seperately doesn't mean anything, as your loss will be defined relative the the input and output of the _seperate models_, not over the entire thing (which is what you want, as you train your entire model (root+2branches)) end-to-end. You'll need to define a custom loss function with multiple outputs (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680818/keras-custom-loss-as-a-function-of-multiple-outputs/51685637#51685637), and compile the entire model with that loss. No need to `compile` any of the "intermediate" `tf.keras.Models`

Comment: Kinda of what I did (I only compiled `branched_model`, instead of compiling the individual parts), but instead of putting the loss in the compilation, I use the `add_loss` function to add this custom loss then.

Comment: Ah yes indeed! My mistake.