# Keras custom loss - Combining loss of multiple branch

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I have a 2 branch network where one branch outputs regression value and another branch outputs classification label.

```
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[output1, output2])    
model.compile(loss=[my_loss_reg, my_loss_class], optimizer='adam')
```

I want to implement a custom loss function (my_loss_reg()) for the regression branch such that at the regression end I want to add a fraction of the classification loss as follows,

```
def my_loss_reg(y_true, y_pred):
        loss_mse=K.mean(K.sum(K.square(y_true-y_pred)))
        #loss_reg = calculate_classification_loss() # How to implement this? 
        final_loss = some_function(loss_mse, loss_reg) # Can calculate only if loss_reg is available
        return final_loss
```

The `y_true` and `y_pred` are true and predicted regression values at the regression branch. To calculate the   classifcation loss I need the true and predicted classifcation labels, which is not available in `my_loss_reg()`.

My question is how to calculate or access the classifcation loss at the regression end of the network? Similarly, I want to get the regression loss at the classification end while calulating the custom loss function `my_loss_class()` for the classification.

How can I do that? Any code snippets will be helpful. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680818/keras-custom-loss-as-a-function-of-multiple-outputs) but this is no longer valid with the latest version of Tensorflow and Keras.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is simply available in native keras

you can automatically combine multiple losses using `loss_weights` parameter

In the example below I tried to reproduce a task where I combined an `mse` loss for the regression and a `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` for the classification task

```
features,n_sample,n_class = 10, 200, 3

X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample,features))
y = np.random.randint(0,n_class, n_sample)

inp = Input(shape=(features,))
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inp)
hidden = Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(hidden)
out_reg = Dense(features, name='out_reg')(x) # output regression
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(hidden)
out_class = Dense(n_class, activation='softmax', name='out_class')(x) # output classification

model = Model(inp, [out_reg,out_class])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss = {'out_reg':'mse', 'out_class':'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'},
              loss_weights = {'out_reg':1., 'out_class':0.5})

model.fit(X, [X,y], epochs=10)
```

In this specific case, the loss is the result of `1*out_reg + 0.5*out_class`

if you want to put your custom losses you simply have to do in this way

```
def my_loss_reg(y_true, y_pred):
    return ...

def my_loss_class(y_true, y_pred):
    return ...

model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss = {'out_reg':my_loss_reg, 'out_class':my_loss_class},
              loss_weights = {'out_reg':1., 'out_class':0.5})

model.fit(X, [X,y], epochs=10)
```

Comment: this is not what I am looking for. As per your answer the combined loss 1*out_reg + 0.5*out_class will propagate through the shared layer not the individual branch. But I want to customize the loss of individual branch and the loss is a function of the loss of other branch.

Comment: remember that a SINGLE loss is minimized (the combined loss of all the outputs). you can't minimize each branch independently in the same network

Comment: As per my understanding individual branch has individual loss values (that's why they are  individual). The shared layers has the combined loss.

Comment: I found this solution but the solution is no longer valid with the latest versions of TensorFlow and Keras. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680818/keras-custom-loss-as-a-function-of-multiple-outputs

Comment: @Saikat u are wrong... from the documentation: 'If the model has multiple outputs... The loss value that will be minimized by the model will then be the sum of all individual losses' (as reasonable) https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile